# Compare files with checksum relative to each others path?

Tags: fdupes

I've merged multiple backups together of all my photography files and came across multiple copies of many files. Not all files are copies and some are photoshopped ones. Now I noticed 'fdupes' that can help me identify duplicates and delete each.

Now there is one issue..

Let's say I've got this folder structure:

```
/Photoshoot X copy 1/*
/Photoshoot X copy 1/selection/*

/Photoshoot X copy 2/*
/Photoshoot X copy 2/selection/*
```

Many, if not all, files in `copy 2` are duplicates of those in `copy 1`. Those can be deleted. However! Some, if not all, files inside the folder `selection` are direct duplicates of those found in the root folder. Those should **not** be deleted, even though they are duplicates. They should not be deleted because, even though they are duplicates, they are copied because these are the important ones out of the whole collection.

Now my question:
is it possible to batch compare files relative to it's path?

*So only both root folders are compared, not the root folder compared to the content of the folder `selection`.*

Comment: Would a workflow like moving the whole `/Photoshoot X copy 2/selection/*` directory some place protected, or archiving it someplace, running `fdupes`, and then restoring the protected copies work for you?

Comment: I already was thinking of such method. I would do it differently. Copy all relative content to a work folder and run fdupes on that.

Comment: Oops. I pressed enter too quickly. However.. I've got about a thousand separate sets of content to scan.. So it will be quite a task. Therefor I would like a bit more optimal suggestion/work flow..

Comment: Well, on linux I could get a list of (probably) duplicated files with something like `find basedirectory -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | grep -v "/selection/" | sort> list.txt`, and look for lines with duplicate md5's. (probably with a `perl` script)  But I don't think that's your environment

Comment: All data is stored on a Synology NAS which as far as I know it's os is based on Linux. I've got access to both a Mac and Windows machine directly connected to the NAS. So you tell me what I need :p :)

Comment: Unless you can get a shell prompt on the Linux running on the NAS, you probably can't do what I'm thinking.   You probably could install Cygwin on the windows machine and get unix-ish commands and do it,  but that may be a steep learning curve to use.  Plus writing the perl script

Comment: I see that `fdupes` exists in the Linux world.   So you could even use that instead of sorting md5 files.   Just use `fdupes -f basedirectory/ > filelist.txt` to get a list of files.   Use `grep` to throw away the lines with `/select/` in them,  then edit `filelist.txt` and put a `rm ` at the front of each line with a global search and replace.. Save and `sh -x filelist.txt` to execute all the `rm` commands.  Easy peezy, right?  :)

Comment: That is pretty smart. I'll try that tonight. Thanks mate. Convert your comment in an answer :p

Answer (score 1):

In a Linux environment one could install `fdupes`

Step 1, get a list of duplicate files

`fdupes -f basedirectory/ > list.txt`

Step 2, filter out the duplicates in the `/selection/` directories

`grep -v "/selection/" list.txt > script.sh`

Step 3 make `script.sh` into a script to delete the files using global search and replace to put a delete command, `rm` at the start of every line.  Use your favorite text editor,  or `sed` if you feel up to it. *Check your  work here, these are the files that go away.*  Take care if you have file names with spaces or other special characters in them.  You might have to put a `rm "` at the start of the line and a `"` at the end to work around that.

`perl -p -i -e 's/^(.*)$/rm "\1"/' script.sh`

should work, but check out the file afterward before executing to make sure it is what you want.

Step 4 execute your new script.  This is pulling the trigger.

`sh -x script.sh`

Step 5 clean up by getting rid of the temporary files `list.txt` and `script.sh`

No doubt one could modify the workflow for windows command line with suitable subsitutions.

Comment: A quick thought of which I preferred to private message you.. Do you think you can realize a script that only searches the direct content of the folders 'copy 1', 'copy 2', 'copy '3, etc. which resize in some of the folders inside /shoots/; e.g.: '/shoots/modelA/copy 1', '/shoots/modelB/copy 2', '/shoots/modelC/copy 3'. So if random folder inside /shoots/ doesn't contain a folder called 'copy #' it skips the parent folder (e.g. 'modelC'). - And it doesn't scan any deeper but the folder 'copy #'. .. Do you understand? xD See illustration: http://i.imgur.com/uUgBJ84.jpg only scan folder /w check

Comment: The reason for this is sometimes a folder doesn't contains a folder called 'copy' and not all additional folders are called 'selection'. So to 'easify' this process, only the folders 'copy #' should be processed. - If this can be realized, please add it as a secondary part of your answer. I couldn't thank you enough. Update: I'll make a new question for this task as this is somewhat different.

Comment: New question: http://superuser.com/questions/1056972/compare-checksum-with-fdupes-only-for-folders-with-a-specific-name - Big thanks if you are willing to help.

Answer (score 1):

Run the perl script `findDups.pl` below on your mac (replacing `dir_to_scan` with the directory to scan for duplicates):

`$ findDups.pl dir_to_scan > rmdups.sh`

have a final look at the script `rmdups.sh` before running it with:

`$ sh rmdups.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Usage: findDups.pl dir_to_scan
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find 'find';
use Digest::MD5 'md5';

my $dir = shift @ARGV || '.';
my %files;

find(\&wanted, $dir);

sub wanted {
  my $localname = $_;
  my $path = $File::Find::name;
  return if $path =~ m#/selection/#;
  return unless -f $localname;
  my $md5 = md5($localname);
  push(@{$files{$md5}}, $path);
}

while (my($key, $value) = each(%files)) {
  while (@{$files{$key}} > 1) {
    my $doomed = shift @{$files{$key}};
    print 'rm \'' . $doomed . '\'' . $/;
  }
}
```