# Compare checksum with Fdupes only for folders with a specific name?

Tags: fdupes

Let me write this without any context and hopefully as easy as possible.

**Perhaps the most easy way of describing this is:**

1. search for all folders named "copy 1", "copy 2", "copy 3"  inside /shoots/*/
2. list all folders
3. run "fdupes -d -n" on each folder, **not** recursive'

---

My bit more practical way of going at this, based upon previous answer by @infixed ( [Compare files with checksum relative to each others path?](https://superuser.com/questions/1056854/compare-files-with-checksum-relative-to-each-others-path/1056920#1056920)). Note: I don't know Linux very well. Most likely the below commands are false..

1. cd /volume1/Modelshoots/shoots/
2. ls
   // to list all folders inside /shoots/
3. cd /*/ each
   // to list all folders inside each folder that exists inside /shoots/
4. grep -v "copy 1" list.txt > script.sh
5. grep -v "copy 2" list.txt > script.sh
6. grep -v "copy 3" list.txt > script.sh
   // To exclude all folders but those that contain a folder called 'copy 1', 'copy 2', 'copy 3'
7. add `'fdupes -d'` in front of each line/path
   // To let the command `fdupes -d` be run for each path that contains 'copy #'.
8. execute the script

---

**More clarification:**

I want to run `fdupes` to delete duplicate identical files in my uncle's huge collection of photoshoots & backups. I want to only scan the folders called 'copy 1', 'copy 2', 'copy 3', etc. which resize in a variety of folder inside the folder 'shoots'. But **not** the folders inside 'copy #'.

See this image for clarification:
[image]

The root folder (/shoots/) and each shoot folder isn't processed (model A, model B, etc.) and neither are other contained folders (selection) processed. The only folders that need to be scanned are the folders called 'copy 1', 'copy 2', etc. However: not any deeper! So the folder 'selection' inside 'copy 1' or the folder 'copy 1' inside 'copy 2' should not be scanned!

Comment: I'm guessing that if you want to find duplicates between `'/shoots/model A/copy 1/'` and `'/shoots/model B/copy 2/'` that you'll need to run `dupes -f` pointing at `/shoots` or it won't find common files.  Just guessing that there might be shots have both A and B in them.   Please also say if the level 2 folders literally start with the word `model`, or that the strings are more complex

Comment: 1. I don't want to run dupes any deeper than the folder 'copy #', therefor running `fdupes -r` is not an option. The folders inside `copy #` contain duplicates  of the content inside 'copy', but should not be deleted since these are the selection of all image from the photoshoot. So every folder inside 'copy #' should be ignored/excluded. And 2. The level 2 folders are called '<model name> - <date>'. So not just `model`, so it's more complex..

Comment: I'm not you have that explained right, because I see no folder called simply "copy".  Are you concerned about duplicates between `'/shoots/model A/copy 1/'` and `'/shoots/model B/copy 2/'`, because that would have to be picked up someway, and `fdupes` can't magically know there is a connection without a common root

Comment: If this is the only archive of this data, I'm going to suggest that instead of deleting the files in one step, you should move the files that you think are duplicates from `'shoots/model X/copy Y/'` into a directory `'shoots/model X/copy Y/dups/'  (that has to be made), so the operation is reversible if someone messes up.  I know it might take a long time to duplicate, but you should consider duplicating the whole dataset, and play with the duplicate before throwing away any files forever

Comment: fyi; `copy #` = `copy 1`, `copy 2`, `copy 3`, etc.. // Anything in `modelA/*` is different than what's inside `modelB/*`, etc. I simply want a list of all folders third level folders called copy # inside /shoots/, such as `/shoots/modelA/copy1` and `/shoots/modelB/copy2`. I only want to scan the children FILES (not folder) of those files and delete all identical copies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37488/discussion-between-sander-schaeffer-and-infixed).

Answer (score 0):

Though not a complete solution to your problem if it were a little more complex, you can use [jdupes](https://github.com/jbruchon/jdupes) with the **-X nostr** or **-X onlystr** option to filter by a substring. However, I've noticed that--for your exact use case--it's much easier than that:

```
cd /volume1/Modelshoots/shoots/
jdupes */copy*/
jdupes -dN */copy*/
```

This will NON-RECURSIVELY scan every file in each directory matching the pattern /volume1/Modelshoots/shoots/*/copy*/ which you'll note doesn't include shoots/*/ or shoots/*/copy*/*/ directories at all. No need to build file lists and fiddle with intermediate commands and mess with substrings; just tell jdupes not to follow subdirectories. The first invocation shows you a list of matches; the second deletes all duplicates without prompting.